# Regex Match Multiple Values From the Same Line

Tags: regex

I'm using https://regexr.com/ for this testing.

**Regex:**
`(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\ (?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d))|(C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe)|\.exe`

**Sample Log:**

```
2020/02/24 09:28:11 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe notepad.exe

2020/02/24 10:23:22

2020/02/24 10:23:59

2020/02/24 10:23:22 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe netstat.exe

2020/02/24 10:37:21 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe nslookup.exe
```

**Need help with:** I want get the date and time, C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe, and the executable from the **same line**. The problem occurred is that it matches all the date. I want to get the date/time along with other 2 criteria and not just lines with date/time on it.

The results I want to get are:

```
1. 2020/02/24 09:28:11 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe notepad.exe
2. 2020/02/24 10:23:22 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe netstat.exe
3. 2020/02/24 10:37:21 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe nslookup.exe
```

Comment: You selected an answer after the minimum waiting time, then changed the selection to another answer, then reading a comment pointing out a weakness in that answer changed the selection back to your original one, then went back to #2. There is no rush to select an answer! Most here wait at least a couple of hours before doing so; some wait longer, giving time for other answers to appear and allowing readers to review and comment on the answers given. Moreover, quick-draw selections can discourage other answers and imo are discourteous to those still working on answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
^(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(.+?\.exe\s.+?\.exe)$
```

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP5kBj/2/)

This regex gets you the 3 results your looking for:

```
1. 2020/02/24 09:28:11 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe notepad.exe
2. 2020/02/24 10:23:22 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe netstat.exe
3. 2020/02/24 10:37:21 C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe nslookup.exe
```

(see the demo link)

Comment: This matches "2020/02/24 10:37:21 my dog has fleas.exe My cat does too.exe".

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Yes true, but it allows flexibility for the various different file paths.  You could go as strict as you want here, but I assumed the OP may want some flexibility and still have it match with different file paths.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of capturing groups and specify all the parts that you want to match without making use of the alternation `|`

```
^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}) ((?:[01]\d|2[0123]):[012345]\d:[012345]\d) (C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd\.exe) (\S+\.exe)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})` Capture **group 1** Match a date like pattern
- `((?:[01]\d|2[0123]):[012345]\d:[012345]\d)` Capture **group 2** Match a time like pattern
- `(C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd\.exe)` Capture **group 3** Match the windows path
- `(\S+\.exe)` Capture **group 4** Match 1+ whitespace chars, a dot and `exe`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s2uCXn/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`((\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (C:\\\\windows\\\\system32\\\\cmd\.exe) (.*\.exe))`

Or

`((\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd\.exe) (.*\.exe))`